# validação de um campo de outra tabela num modelo específico

Tags: ruby-on-rails

É possível validar o campo de um outra tabela que esteja relacionada num modelo específico?

Por exemplo, eu preciso validar um campo e-mail numa tabela *Pedidos*, mas apenas e-mails de quem for um usuário interno (que está numa tabela *Users*). Ou seja, quem for um usuário interno deve digitar seu e-mail. Essa informação vem do login (devise), ou seja, de outra tabela (pedidos `belongs_to` user).

Nisso, no modelo pedidos, estou criando uma def de validacao assim:

```
def valida_email_interno
   errors.add(:email, "Digite o email") if email.blank? and ...# a  condição que o usuario é interno, por exemplo, @pedido.user.localpedido == 1
```

Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 0):

em primeiro lugar eu sugiro que você crie um método para verificar se é um usuário interno (pelo que entendi apenas verificar se está associado a um user), por exemplo:

```rb
def usuario_interno?
  user # Ou qualquer outra lógica
end
```

Depois disso você pode fazer uma validação normal do rails:

```rb
validates_presence_of :email, if: :usuario_interno?
```